# Unable to update Node JS - keeps returning to old version [Ubuntu 15.04]

Tags: apt, upgrade, 15.04, nodejs, curl

I'm unable to update nodejs, and I can't see why.

If I were to make a guess, I'd say that I have two repositories listed in apt-get, that both contain a nodejs package.

Here's what I've done:

Remove old version:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nodejs npm
```

Then, going by https://github.com/nodesource/distributions#installation-instructions, I've run:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -
```

And then:

```
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

I then run:

```
nodejs -v
```

Which returns:

```
v0.10.25
```

Can anyone explain what's going wrong? And how I can remedy this situation?

Many thanks.

Comment: You'll want to figure out where your current version of Node is coming from.  `which nodejs` will tell you that. Then, run `apt-get remove...` again and see what the output of `which nodejs` is after attempting to remove it.

Comment: which nodejs isn't found. It uninstalls it completely when I use remove.

Comment: In case anyone else finds this question here. I had the same problem. I decided to install NVM to use it for different versions. The instructions said to close the terminal and open a new one after installing NVM. I did and decided to randomly check the current node version. It had changed to the newly installed one. I'm not sure if installing NVM did anything, I'd think not, so anyone with the same problem might want to try to close the terminal and open a new one and then run node --version.

Comment: It is the npm that comes with node via apt. It is worthless. Not only does it not install nor does it update ANYTHING, but after using it 3-4 times, I now have a giant memory leak which kills my pc in about 3 hours. Thank god for Timeshift.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end I was sick of getting nowhere.

As a fix, I decided to use nvm (node version manager).

It's super simple to install, setup and use. Took less than 3 minutes to get back up and running with nodejs version 5.

https://github.com/creationix/nvm

I'm writing this for completeness.

Comment: Awesome! Glad you found something that works. NVM is my preferred way of installing Node on Ubuntu as well.

Answer (score 24):

Using the nvm (node version manager) is the best option to update the default version of node.

1. install or update nvm:

   ```
   curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
   ```

   or

   ```
   wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.33.2/install.sh | bash
   ```
2. After successful installation, close the terminal and open a new terminal.
   List the version of nodejs available:

   ```
   nvm ls-remote
   ```

   This will list the available versions of nodejs.
3. Select the version you want to install:

   ```
   nvm install xxxxxx
   ```
4. Check the version:

   ```
   node -v
   ```

Hope this helps as a step by step guide.

Comment: Nice answer, exactly what I wanted!

Comment: clean solution even in 2024

Answer (score 3):

I always use [n](https://www.npmjs.com/package/n) to do update, upgrade and remove `node` versions. Note that you might have to use `sudo`, depending on your configuration.

```
$ npm install -g n
```

Use or install the latest official release:

```
$ n latest
```

Use or install the stable official release:

```
$ n stable
```

Use or install the latest LTS official release:

```
$ n lts
```

Removing Versions

```
$ n rm 0.9.4 v0.10.0
```