# Even after update node -v shows older version

Tags: nodejs, npm

I am trying to update node version. Even after updating node to v10.x it still shows older v8.x. I have added  path where npm and node is installed and node and npm version. I also used nvm.
I have installed and removed it multiple times so i don't know where it is installed. I am new to linux and completely clueless. Please help.

```
   amrit@amrits-pc ~ $ whereis npm
npm: /usr/bin/npm /usr/local/bin/npm /home/amrit/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/npm

amrit@amrits-pc ~ $ whereis node
node: /usr/bin/node /usr/lib/node /usr/local/bin/node /home/amrit/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/node

amrit@amrits-pc ~ $ n 10.16.0
   installed : v10.16.0 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v8.11.2 at /home/amrit/.nvm/versions/node/v8.11.2/bin/node

amrit@amrits-pc ~ $ node -v
v8.11.2

amrit@amrits-pc ~ $ npm -v
6.14.4
```

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/711834/unable-to-update-node-js-keeps-returning-to-old-version-ubuntu-15-04. the query was resolved using this thread.

Answer (score 2):

This command change default alias to your version: `nvm alias default 10.16`

Comment: Thanks i followed https://askubuntu.com/questions/711834/unable-to-update-node-js-keeps-returning-to-old-version-ubuntu-15-04 to resolve this but there was a weird popup everytime i opened terminal. "N/A: version "N/A -> N/A" is not yet installed.

You need to run "nvm install N/A" to install it before using it"  Your answer helped to resolve this.